# High CPU Load, Crashes frequently

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, php5

I have been struggling the past few days to keep my server up and running.  The load averages hover around 2 and peak in the double digits until it crashes.

Currently I am on a cloud VPS with WHM and Cpanel:
CENTOS 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64
2G RAM
Speed 2393.998 MHz
Cache 4096 KB
Apache/2.4.7 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
PHP Version 5.4.23

I am running the following CMS on the server:
1 X Wordpress
1 x SMF Forum
1 x Drupal 7

MySQL tuner result:

```
MySQLTuner 1.2.0 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.34-cll
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 165M (Tables: 226)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 65M (Tables: 334)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 309

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 58m 57s (44K q [12.588 qps], 1K conn, TX: 84M, RX: 10M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 64% / 36%
[--] Total buffers: 210.0M global + 7.6M per thread (100 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 972.5M (51% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (25/44K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 11% (11/100)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 24.0M/108.2M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 98.2% (261K cached / 4K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 70.1% (23K cached / 33K selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 57941
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 824 sorts)
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 41% (126 on disk / 302 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 97% (40 created / 1K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 95% (230 open / 241 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 6% (156/2K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (25K immediate / 25K locks)
[OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 65.4M/140.0M

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (> 10M)
    tmp_table_size (> 20M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 20M)
```

I see the following in my messages log:

```
Jan 14 08:22:31 server1 kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 20781 (php) score 4 or sacrifice child
Jan 14 08:22:31 server1 kernel: Killed process 20781, UID 504, (php) total-vm:266888kB, anon-rss:3268kB, file-rss:1604kB
Jan 14 08:25:52 server1 kernel: php invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x200da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: php cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: Pid: 21549, comm: php Not tainted 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: Call Trace:
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff810d05c1>] ? cpuset_print_task_mems_allowed+0x91/0xb0
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff81122970>] ? dump_header+0x90/0x1b0
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8122799c>] ? security_real_capable_noaudit+0x3c/0x70
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff81122df2>] ? oom_kill_process+0x82/0x2a0
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff81122d31>] ? select_bad_process+0xe1/0x120
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff81123230>] ? out_of_memory+0x220/0x3c0
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8112fb4c>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x8ac/0x8d0
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff81167baa>] ? alloc_pages_vma+0x9a/0x150
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8115b882>] ? read_swap_cache_async+0xf2/0x160
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8115c3a9>] ? valid_swaphandles+0x69/0x150
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8115b977>] ? swapin_readahead+0x87/0xc0
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8114ac4d>] ? handle_pte_fault+0x6dd/0xb00
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8104eeb7>] ? pte_alloc_one+0x37/0x50
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8114b29a>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x22a/0x300
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8114f336>] ? vma_adjust+0x556/0x5e0
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8104a8d8>] ? __do_page_fault+0x138/0x480
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8100988e>] ? __switch_to+0x26e/0x320
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff81527920>] ? thread_return+0x4e/0x76e
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8103ea79>] ? kvm_clock_get_cycles+0x9/0x10
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8152d46e>] ? do_page_fault+0x3e/0xa0
Jan 14 08:26:08 server1 kernel: [<ffffffff8152a825>] ? page_fault+0x25/0x30
```

My dmesg log:

```
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Linux version 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b10.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014
Command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/vg0-root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg0/swap rd_NO_MD quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb crashkernel=auto rd_NO_DM  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_LVM_LV=vg0/root
KERNEL supported cpus:
  Intel GenuineIntel
  AMD AuthenticAMD
  Centaur CentaurHauls
Disabled fast string operations
BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
 BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009f400 (usable)
 BIOS-e820: 000000000009f400 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
 BIOS-e820: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
 BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 000000007fffd000 (usable)
 BIOS-e820: 000000007fffd000 - 0000000080000000 (reserved)
 BIOS-e820: 00000000fffbc000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
DMI 2.4 present.
SMBIOS version 2.4 @ 0xFDA10
DMI: Red Hat KVM, BIOS 0.5.1 01/01/2007
Hypervisor detected: KVM
e820 update range: 0000000000000000 - 0000000000001000 (usable) ==> (reserved)
e820 remove range: 00000000000a0000 - 0000000000100000 (usable)
last_pfn = 0x7fffd max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
MTRR default type: write-back
MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
  00000-9FFFF write-back
  A0000-BFFFF uncachable
  C0000-FFFFF write-protect
MTRR variable ranges enabled:
  0 base 00E0000000 mask FFE0000000 uncachable
  1 disabled
  2 disabled
  3 disabled
  4 disabled
  5 disabled
  6 disabled
  7 disabled
PAT not supported by CPU.
initial memory mapped : 0 - 20000000
init_memory_mapping: 0000000000000000-000000007fffd000
 0000000000 - 007fe00000 page 2M
 007fe00000 - 007fffd000 page 4k
kernel direct mapping tables up to 7fffd000 @ 8000-c000
RAMDISK: 36f8c000 - 37fefeb5
ACPI: RSDP 00000000000fd9e0 00014 (v00 BOCHS )
ACPI: RSDT 000000007fffd640 00034 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCRSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
ACPI: FACP 000000007ffffe20 00074 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCFACP 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
ACPI: DSDT 000000007fffd8c0 024F1 (v01   BXPC   BXDSDT 00000001 INTL 20090123)
ACPI: FACS 000000007ffffdc0 00040
ACPI: SSDT 000000007fffd7c0 000FF (v01 BOCHS  BXPCSSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
ACPI: APIC 000000007fffd6d0 00080 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCAPIC 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
ACPI: SSDT 000000007fffd680 0004E (v01   BXPC BXSSDTPC 00000001 INTL 20090123)
ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
Setting APIC routing to flat.
No NUMA configuration found
Faking a node at 0000000000000000-000000007fffd000
Bootmem setup node 0 0000000000000000-000000007fffd000
  NODE_DATA [000000000000a000 - 000000000003dfff]
  bootmap [000000000003e000 -  000000000004dfff] pages 10
(7 early reservations) ==> bootmem [0000000000 - 007fffd000]
  #0 [0000000000 - 0000001000]   BIOS data page ==> [0000000000 - 0000001000]
  #1 [0000006000 - 0000008000]       TRAMPOLINE ==> [0000006000 - 0000008000]
  #2 [0001000000 - 000201faa4]    TEXT DATA BSS ==> [0001000000 - 000201faa4]
  #3 [0036f8c000 - 0037fefeb5]          RAMDISK ==> [0036f8c000 - 0037fefeb5]
  #4 [000009f400 - 0000100000]    BIOS reserved ==> [000009f400 - 0000100000]
  #5 [0002020000 - 0002020081]              BRK ==> [0002020000 - 0002020081]
  #6 [0000008000 - 000000a000]          PGTABLE ==> [0000008000 - 000000a000]
found SMP MP-table at [ffff8800000fda30] fda30
Reserving 129MB of memory at 48MB for crashkernel (System RAM: 2047MB)
kvm-clock: Using msrs 4b564d01 and 4b564d00
kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 0:1c247c1, boot clock
 [ffffea0000000000-ffffea00009fffff] PMD -> [ffff880002600000-ffff880002ffffff] on node 0
 [ffffea0000a00000-ffffea0001bfffff] PMD -> [ffff88000b200000-ffff88000c3fffff] on node 0
Zone PFN ranges:
  DMA      0x00000001 -> 0x00001000
  DMA32    0x00001000 -> 0x00100000
  Normal   0x00100000 -> 0x00100000
Movable zone start PFN for each node
early_node_map[2] active PFN ranges
    0: 0x00000001 -> 0x0000009f
    0: 0x00000100 -> 0x0007fffd
On node 0 totalpages: 524187
  DMA zone: 56 pages used for memmap
  DMA zone: 101 pages reserved
  DMA zone: 3841 pages, LIFO batch:0
  DMA32 zone: 7112 pages used for memmap
  DMA32 zone: 513077 pages, LIFO batch:31
ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0xb008
ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
Setting APIC routing to flat.
ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x01] enabled)
ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] dfl dfl lint[0x1])
ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x00] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 0, version 17, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 5 global_irq 5 high level)
ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 10 global_irq 10 high level)
ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 11 global_irq 11 high level)
ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
ACPI: IRQ2 used by override.
ACPI: IRQ5 used by override.
ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
ACPI: IRQ10 used by override.
ACPI: IRQ11 used by override.
Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
SMP: Allowing 2 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
nr_irqs_gsi: 24
PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009f000 - 00000000000a0000
PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 00000000000f0000
PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000
Allocating PCI resources starting at 80000000 (gap: 80000000:7ffbc000)
Booting paravirtualized kernel on KVM
NR_CPUS:4096 nr_cpumask_bits:2 nr_cpu_ids:2 nr_node_ids:1
PERCPU: Embedded 31 pages/cpu @ffff880002200000 s94872 r8192 d23912 u1048576
pcpu-alloc: s94872 r8192 d23912 u1048576 alloc=1*2097152
pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 1 
kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 0:22167c1, primary cpu clock
kvm-stealtime: cpu 0, msr 220e880
Built 1 zonelists in Node order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 516918
Policy zone: DMA32
Kernel command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/vg0-root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg0/swap rd_NO_MD quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb crashkernel=129M@0M rd_NO_DM  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_LVM_LV=vg0/root
PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Checking aperture...
No AGP bridge found
Memory: 1901928k/2097140k available (5325k kernel code, 392k absent, 194820k reserved, 7013k data, 1276k init)
Hierarchical RCU implementation.
NR_IRQS:33024 nr_irqs:424
Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
console [tty0] enabled
allocated 8388608 bytes of page_cgroup
please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
Detected 2393.998 MHz processor.
Calibrating delay loop (skipped) preset value.. 4787.99 BogoMIPS (lpj=2393998)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Security Framework initialized
SELinux:  Initializing.
SELinux:  Starting in permissive mode
Dentry cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
Mount-cache hash table entries: 256
Initializing cgroup subsys ns
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Initializing cgroup subsys memory
Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
Disabled fast string operations
mce: CPU supports 10 MCE banks
alternatives: switching to unfair spinlock
ACPI: Core revision 20090903
ftrace: converting mcount calls to 0f 1f 44 00 00
ftrace: allocating 21769 entries in 86 pages
APIC routing finalized to flat.
..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
CPU0: Intel QEMU Virtual CPU version (cpu64-rhel6) stepping 03
Performance Events: Broken PMU hardware detected, using software events only.
NMI watchdog disabled (cpu0): hardware events not enabled
Booting Node   0, Processors  #1 Ok.
kvm-clock: cpu 1, msr 0:23167c1, secondary cpu clock
Disabled fast string operations
kvm-stealtime: cpu 1, msr 230e880
Brought up 2 CPUs
Total of 2 processors activated (9575.99 BogoMIPS).
sizeof(vma)=200 bytes
sizeof(page)=56 bytes
sizeof(inode)=592 bytes
sizeof(dentry)=192 bytes
sizeof(ext3inode)=800 bytes
sizeof(buffer_head)=104 bytes
sizeof(skbuff)=232 bytes
sizeof(task_struct)=2648 bytes
devtmpfs: initialized
regulator: core version 0.5
NET: Registered protocol family 16
ACPI: bus type pci registered
PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
ACPI: EC: Look up EC in DSDT
ACPI: Interpreter enabled
ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
ACPI: No dock devices found.
PCI: Ignoring host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=use_crs" and report a bug
ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [io  0x0000-0x0cf7] (ignored)
pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [io  0x0d00-0xffff] (ignored)
pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff] (ignored)
pci_root PNP0A03:00: host bridge window [mem 0xe0000000-0xfebfffff] (ignored)
PCI: root bus 00: using default resources
PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0xffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x00000000-0xffffffffff]
pci 0000:00:01.1: reg 20: [io  0xc000-0xc00f]
pci 0000:00:01.2: reg 20: [io  0xc020-0xc03f]
pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0xb000-0xb03f] claimed by PIIX4 ACPI
pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0xb100-0xb10f] claimed by PIIX4 SMB
pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 10: [mem 0xf0000000-0xf1ffffff pref]
pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 14: [mem 0xf2000000-0xf2000fff]
pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 30: [mem 0xf2010000-0xf201ffff pref]
pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 10: [mem 0xf2020000-0xf203ffff]
pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 14: [io  0xc040-0xc07f]
pci 0000:00:03.0: reg 30: [mem 0xf2040000-0xf205ffff pref]
pci 0000:00:04.0: reg 10: [io  0xc080-0xc09f]
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0._PRT]
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKS] (IRQs 9) *0
vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
vgaarb: loaded
vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
SCSI subsystem initialized
libata version 3.00 loaded.
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
PCI: old code would have set cacheline size to 32 bytes, but clflush_size = 64
PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
NetLabel: Initializing
NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
Switching to clocksource kvm-clock
pnp: PnP ACPI init
ACPI: bus type pnp registered
pnp 00:00: [io  0x0cf8-0x0cff]
pnp 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0a03 (active)
pnp 00:01: [io  0x0070-0x0071]
pnp 00:01: [irq 8]
pnp 00:01: [io  0x0072-0x0077]
pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
pnp 00:02: [io  0x0060]
pnp 00:02: [io  0x0064]
pnp 00:02: [irq 1]
pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
pnp 00:03: [irq 12]
pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0f13 (active)
pnp 00:04: [io  0x03f2-0x03f5]
pnp 00:04: [io  0x03f7]
pnp 00:04: [irq 6]
pnp 00:04: [dma 2]
pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0700 (active)
pnp 00:05: [io  0x03f8-0x03ff]
pnp 00:05: [irq 4]
pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0501 (active)
pnp: PnP ACPI: found 6 devices
ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp unregistered
PCI: max bus depth: 0 pci_try_num: 1
pci_bus 0000:00: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0xffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: resource 5 [mem 0x00000000-0xffffffffff]
ipmi message handler version 39.2
IPMI System Interface driver.
ipmi_si: Adding default-specified kcs state machine
ipmi_si: Trying default-specified kcs state machine at i/o address 0xca2, slave address 0x0, irq 0
ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
ipmi_si: Adding default-specified smic state machine
ipmi_si: Trying default-specified smic state machine at i/o address 0xca9, slave address 0x0, irq 0
ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
ipmi_si: Adding default-specified bt state machine
ipmi_si: Trying default-specified bt state machine at i/o address 0xe4, slave address 0x0, irq 0
ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
ipmi_si: Unable to find any System Interface(s)
input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0
ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
ACPI: acpi_idle registered with cpuidle
ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, No or invalid critical threshold (20090903/thermal-386)
GHES: HEST is not enabled!
Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
Linux agpgart interface v0.103
crash memory driver: version 1.1
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
00:05: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
input: Macintosh mouse button emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input1
Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: PCI INT D -> Link[LNKD] -> GSI 11 (level, high) -> IRQ 11
uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: setting latency timer to 64
uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: UHCI Host Controller
uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: irq 11, io base 0x0000c020
usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
usb usb1: Product: UHCI Host Controller
usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 uhci_hcd
usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:01.2
usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBD,PNP0f13:MOU] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
rtc_cmos 00:01: RTC can wake from S4
rtc_cmos 00:01: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
rtc0: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram
cpuidle: using governor ladder
cpuidle: using governor menu
EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: v2.6:USB HID core driver
GRE over IPv4 demultiplexor driver
TCP cubic registered
Initializing XFRM netlink socket
NET: Registered protocol family 17
registered taskstats version 1
rtc_cmos 00:01: setting system clock to 2014-01-14 06:41:15 UTC (1389681675)
Initalizing network drop monitor service
Freeing unused kernel memory: 1276k freed
Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 10240k
Freeing unused kernel memory: 800k freed
Freeing unused kernel memory: 1584k freed
dracut: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2
dracut: rd_NO_LUKS: removing cryptoluks activation
device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
device-mapper: ioctl: 4.24.6-ioctl (2013-01-15) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
udev: starting version 147
dracut: Starting plymouth daemon
usb 1-1: new full speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
dracut: rd_NO_DM: removing DM RAID activation
dracut: rd_NO_MD: removing MD RAID activation
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0627, idProduct=0001
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=5
usb 1-1: Product: QEMU USB Tablet
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: QEMU 0.12.1
usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 42
usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
ata_piix 0000:00:01.1: version 2.13
ata_piix 0000:00:01.1: setting latency timer to 64
scsi0 : ata_piix
scsi1 : ata_piix
ata1: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xc000 irq 14
ata2: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xc008 irq 15
Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2393.890 MHz.
input: ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3
input: QEMU 0.12.1 QEMU USB Tablet as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input4
generic-usb 0003:0627:0001.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v0.01 Pointer [QEMU 0.12.1 QEMU USB Tablet] on usb-0000:00:01.2-1/input0
ata1.01: NODEV after polling detection
ata1.00: ATA-7: QEMU HARDDISK, 0.12.1, max UDMA/100
ata1.00: 125829120 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 
ata2.01: NODEV after polling detection
ata2.00: ATAPI: QEMU DVD-ROM, 0.12.1, max UDMA/100
ata1.00: configured for MWDMA2
scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      QEMU HARDDISK    0.12 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
ata2.00: configured for MWDMA2
scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            QEMU     QEMU DVD-ROM     0.12 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
virtio-pci 0000:00:04.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKD] -> GSI 11 (level, high) -> IRQ 11
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 125829120 512-byte logical blocks: (64.4 GB/60.0 GiB)
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 sda: sda1 sda2
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 4x/4x xa/form2 tray
Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
dracut: Scanning devices sda2  for LVM logical volumes vg0/swap vg0/root 
dracut: inactive '/dev/vg0/tmp' [2.00 GiB] inherit
dracut: inactive '/dev/vg0/root' [53.80 GiB] inherit
dracut: inactive '/dev/vg0/swap' [4.00 GiB] inherit
EXT4-fs (dm-0): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
EXT4-fs (dm-0): write access will be enabled during recovery
EXT4-fs (dm-0): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
EXT4-fs (dm-0): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1835258
EXT4-fs (dm-0): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 2754263
EXT4-fs (dm-0): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 2752522
EXT4-fs (dm-0): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1837359
EXT4-fs (dm-0): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1837354
EXT4-fs (dm-0): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1835927
EXT4-fs (dm-0): 6 orphan inodes deleted
EXT4-fs (dm-0): recovery complete
EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
dracut: Remounting /dev/mapper/vg0-root with -o usrquota,ro
EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
dracut: Mounted root filesystem /dev/mapper/vg0-root
dracut: Loading SELinux policy
SELinux: 2048 avtab hash slots, 277800 rules.
SELinux: 2048 avtab hash slots, 277800 rules.
SELinux:  9 users, 12 roles, 3917 types, 217 bools, 1 sens, 1024 cats
SELinux:  81 classes, 277800 rules
SELinux:  Completing initialization.
SELinux:  Setting up existing superblocks.
SELinux: initialized (dev dm-0, type ext4), uses xattr
SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev usbfs, type usbfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev selinuxfs, type selinuxfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev mqueue, type mqueue), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev hugetlbfs, type hugetlbfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev devpts, type devpts), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev inotifyfs, type inotifyfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev anon_inodefs, type anon_inodefs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev pipefs, type pipefs), uses task SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev debugfs, type debugfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev sockfs, type sockfs), uses task SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev devtmpfs, type devtmpfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev proc, type proc), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev bdev, type bdev), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev rootfs, type rootfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev sysfs, type sysfs), uses genfs_contexts
type=1403 audit(1389681680.167:2): policy loaded auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
dracut: 
dracut: Switching root
udev: starting version 147
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
piix4_smbus 0000:00:01.3: SMBus Host Controller at 0xb100, revision 0
e1000: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - version 7.3.21-k8-NAPI
e1000: Copyright (c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation.
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] enabled at IRQ 10
e1000 0000:00:03.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKC] -> GSI 10 (level, high) -> IRQ 10
e1000 0000:00:03.0: setting latency timer to 64
e1000 0000:00:03.0: eth0: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) 06:01:44:00:12:ef
e1000 0000:00:03.0: eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
microcode: CPU0 sig=0x6d3, pf=0x1, revision=0x1
platform microcode: firmware: requesting intel-ucode/06-0d-03
microcode: CPU1 sig=0x6d3, pf=0x1, revision=0x1
platform microcode: firmware: requesting intel-ucode/06-0d-03
Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
SELinux: initialized (dev sda1, type ext2), uses xattr
EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
SELinux: initialized (dev dm-2, type ext4), uses xattr
type=1400 audit(1389681713.367:3): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=785 comm="quotacheck" path="/dev/pts/0" dev=devpts ino=3 scontext=system_u:system_r:quota_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:devpts_t:s0 tclass=chr_file
type=1400 audit(1389681713.424:4): avc:  denied  { module_request } for  pid=787 comm="quotaon" kmod="quota_v1" scontext=system_u:system_r:quota_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=system
Adding 4194296k swap on /dev/mapper/vg0-swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4194296k 
SELinux: initialized (dev binfmt_misc, type binfmt_misc), uses genfs_contexts
```

Here is a sample Cron log:

```
   Jan 13 16:40:01 server1 CROND[7026]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jan 13 16:41:01 server1 CROND[7120]: (oilgasfr) CMD (/tmp/.ICE-unix/components/y2kupdate >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 13 16:42:01 server1 CROND[7281]: (oilgasfr) CMD (/tmp/.ICE-unix/components/y2kupdate >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 13 16:43:01 server1 CROND[7412]: (oilgasfr) CMD (/tmp/.ICE-unix/components/y2kupdate >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

Any idea where I should start?  I've already gone through the whole process of disabling modules and rebuilding Apache.

Thank you

Comment: IOPS measurement? That smells like the typical low cost cheap VPS and those are with a serious reliability terribe in the IO side. Check whether you have IO problems first. My bet would be on that side.

Comment: Hi here is my result: 
root@server1 [~]# dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync
16384+0 records in
16384+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 55.4731 s, 19.4 MB/s

Comment: Useless. IO in non-linear fashions is NEVER measured in MB and by copying a file. Get a tool. Get an IOPS number. The streaming copy operations are terribly - and slow, btw., my own small hyper-v server can copy that thing with around 600mb to 900mb/second.

Comment: This is with Leaseweb, they are well respected?  They already moved me over to another hypervisor last week and yet the issue still persists. What tool would you suggest?  Thanks

Comment: By now I suggest you hire an admin - this site requires you to be a professional admin, and the question you ask now makes me think you are not. What do you mean with well respected? They have low cost offers and if you get a server not matching what you need that is not their problem. They start very cheap and obviously that is not meant for a heavy duty use. Has nothing to do with their reputation.

Comment: However if one wanted to learn why would you hire an admin?  Isn't the purpose of learning going through situations like this and getting advice / researching? While I may not be that good now, in a few years I will be, one of the things I will not be is unhelpful to others to who want to learn too.

Comment: However, if you wanted to learn, you dont go to a place where this is not welcome (read the FAQ) and put up novice questions. You get a book.

Comment: Also, using cpanel is a terrible way to learn.

Comment: I might have Cpanel but I try to do as much as I can via the command line.  I do read a lot of books but there are times when you have to reach out for advice.  As I said before I went through a number of items before posting this question as I was stuck.  You may consider this a novice question but to me it is not.  The resources I have access to do not explain the challenges very well or the solutions are difficult to locate. What would be the point of a site like this? In theory every person who has posted a question on this site should in theory figure out the answer themselves.

Comment: Yes, we _do_ expect everyone to try to figure out the answer themselves before posting here. Using the command line when you are still infected with cPanel isn't very useful, since cPanel itself makes your whole system nonstandard and unsupportable by anyone other than cPanel. Finally, you obviously have issues with running out of memory, but didn't post any relevant information.

Comment: Thank you, in between reading the responses and doing "research" via Google I agree that the challenge here is memory related.  Obviously I am not advanced enough yet to post relevant information.  The reason for posting various blocks of info was that I wasn't really sure what the issue was (my approach to this question was done in that way because I first suspected that this could be more than one type of issue).  As for Cpanel, I don't really want it either (costs money), one day I will not need it, but for now I do. Hopefully I will be able to figure this out on my own and report back.

Answer (score 2):

Out of memory: Kill process 20781 (php) score 4 or sacrifice child
Killed process 20781, UID 504, (php) total-vm:266888kB, anon-rss:3268kB, file-rss:1604kB

You have no more memory to use. Your server can't handle new apache and mysql threads/process anymore (none process infact) and started to die. In this case, you have to increase the RAM. I don't know how many connections your server handled per sec, but in my opinion, 2 Go is no enough.

Check with free -l

Comment: The high load averages might be the result of [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)). High memory usages might also result from mis-configuration (processes are configured to consume too much ram) or memory leaks (process code is faulty and not freeing RAM when it is no longer in use). The latter typically would have a workaround in restarting the affected processes frequently. But adding RAM never hurts performance-wise.

Comment: Thank you.  At a higher level I do suspect the areas you have highlighted.  My challenge however is how to work through it all, in other words a systematic approach to troubleshooting.  I have running various suggestions based on Google Searches and referring to manuals etc but have yielded no results.  Adding more RAM would be my last resort because my server was running with no issues for 3 months and all of a sudden after New Years this is what happened.  Will report back if I do come right.